# How to make Magento saving product faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, magento

**Everything below this line is out of date. Magento is just slow, nothing less and nothing more.**

---

Magento is extremely slow as said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580828/magento-saving-product-is-extremly-slow-but-profiler-shows-it-only-takes-1sec/12583078#12583078

After some struggling due to lack of root privilege on HostGator, I end up profiling Magento calls myself.

Here's one of those results:

`Blue: timing 1982878436 Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote begin` <- this is logged when entering `Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote`'s `save` method.

`Blue: timing 1982878436 Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote 46` <- and this is logged when exiting.

The number `1982878436` is a random number generated as the id of the call. And number `46` is the time taken in seconds.

```
2012-09-26T06:36:16+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 1982878436 Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote begin
2012-09-26T06:36:18+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 645597828 Mage_Log_Model_Mysql4_Visitor begin
2012-09-26T06:36:18+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: 645597828 Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
2012-09-26T06:36:18+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 645597828 Mage_Log_Model_Mysql4_Visitor 0
2012-09-26T06:36:18+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 1712949075 Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote begin
2012-09-26T06:36:24+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 2103820838 Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote begin
2012-09-26T06:36:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 1999314779 Mage_Log_Model_Mysql4_Visitor begin
2012-09-26T06:36:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: 1999314779 Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
2012-09-26T06:36:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 1999314779 Mage_Log_Model_Mysql4_Visitor 0
2012-09-26T06:36:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 504509596 Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote begin
2012-09-26T06:36:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 1887845167 Mage_Log_Model_Mysql4_Visitor begin
2012-09-26T06:36:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 1887845167 Mage_Log_Model_Mysql4_Visitor 0
2012-09-26T06:37:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 1887308594 Mage_GoogleOptimizer_Model_Mysql4_Code begin
2012-09-26T06:37:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 1887308594 Mage_GoogleOptimizer_Model_Mysql4_Code 0
2012-09-26T06:37:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: 504509596 Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
2012-09-26T06:37:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 504509596 Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote 6
2012-09-26T06:37:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: 1982878436 Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
2012-09-26T06:37:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 1982878436 Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote 46
2012-09-26T06:37:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: 1712949075 Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
2012-09-26T06:37:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 1712949075 Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote 44
2012-09-26T06:37:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: 2103820838 Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
2012-09-26T06:37:02+00:00 DEBUG (7): Blue: timing 2103820838 Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote 38
```

As we can see `1982878436`, `1712949075`, `2103820838` are called in parallel, and each took several tens of seconds to finish. I suspect that there is some lock issue among the three calls make them waiting for each other. Sometimes when I'm saving a product, Magento will even report action being failed because MySQL is failed due to deadlock.

Anyone has any ideas about this?

Comment: What is the version of Magento?

Comment: +1 for *"Magento is just slow"* ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ends up just other queries blocked these queries. There two major slow down in this issues.

One is in Mage/Sales/Model/Mysql4/Quote.php, there are two nested queries. I know neither how MySQL's cache works nor how to configure MySQL on HostGator, so I end up caching the query result myself:

```
public function markQuotesRecollectOnCatalogRules()
{
    /*
    $this->_getWriteAdapter()->query("
        UPDATE {$this->getTable('sales/quote')} SET trigger_recollect = 1
        WHERE entity_id IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT quote_id
            FROM {$this->getTable('sales/quote_item')}
            WHERE product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM {$this->getTable('catalogrule/rule_product_price')})
        )"
    );
    */

    $products = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchCol("SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM {$this->getTable('catalogrule/rule_product_price')}");

    $ids = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchCol("
        SELECT DISTINCT quote_id
            FROM {$this->getTable('sales/quote_item')}
            WHERE product_id IN (?)", implode(',', $products)
    );

    if (count($ids) > 0)
    {
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->query("
            UPDATE {$this->getTable('sales/quote')} SET trigger_recollect = 1
                WHERE entity_id IN (?)", implode(',', $ids)
        );
    }
}
```

And

```
public function markQuotesRecollect($productIds)
{
    /*
    $this->_getWriteAdapter()->query("
        UPDATE `{$this->getTable('sales/quote')}` SET `trigger_recollect` = 1
        WHERE `entity_id` IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT `quote_id`
            FROM `{$this->getTable('sales/quote_item')}`
            WHERE `product_id` IN (?)
        )", $productIds
    );
    */

    $ids = $this->_getReadAdapter()->fetchCol("
        SELECT DISTINCT quote_id
            FROM {$this->getTable('sales/quote_item')}
            WHERE product_id IN (?)", $productIds
    );

    if (count($ids) > 0)
    {
        $this->_getWriteAdapter()->query("
            UPDATE {$this->getTable('sales/quote')} SET trigger_recollect = 1
                WHERE entity_id IN (?)", implode(',', $ids)
        );
    }

    return $this;
}
```

And there is the Mage/CatalogRule/Model/Rule.php. Inside, it seems to be a well known reindexing problem.

```
public function applyAllRulesToProduct($product)
{
    $this->_getResource()->applyAllRulesForDateRange(NULL, NULL, $product);
    $this->_invalidateCache();

    /*
    $indexProcess = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
    if ($indexProcess) {
        $indexProcess->reindexAll();
    }
    */

    if ($product instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Product)
    {
        $id = $product->getId();
    }
    else
    {
        $id = $product;
    }

    if ($id)
    {
        $indexer = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_indexer_price');

        if ($indexer)
        {
            $indexer->reindexProductIds(array($id));
        }
    }
}
```

I think making it response to the global setting should be a better way. But I've got no time for it, so I copied this solution.

Answer (score 4):

When running queries inloving `IN`, `MySQL` always makes the outermost table leading.

This means that this query:

```
    UPDATE {$this->getTable('sales/quote')} SET trigger_recollect = 1
    WHERE entity_id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT quote_id
        FROM {$this->getTable('sales/quote_item')}
        WHERE product_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM {$this->getTable('catalogrule/rule_product_price')})
```

will have to scan each record in `sales/quote` and check it against `sales/quote_item` which in its turn will have to check each matched record against `catalogrule/rule_product_price`.

If there are significantly more records in `sales/quote` than the subquery returns, this will be slow.

You may want to rewrite it as a join:

```
UPDATE  {$this->getTable('catalogrule/rule_product_price')} crpp
JOIN    {$this->getTable('sales/quote_item')} sqi
ON      sqi.product_id = crpp.product_id
JOIN    {$this->getTable('sales/quote')} sq
ON      sq.entity_id = sqi.quote_id
SET     sq.trigger_recollect = 1
```

This way, optimizer may choose which table to make the leading (when every join field is indexed, it should be the smallest table).